# How we can migrate cloud function one project to another project across the organisation in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud so I'm hoping for some guidance around "organizations".

Can I move a cloud function project from one project to another? Across the organisations.I'm new to Google Cloud so I'm hoping for some guidance around "organizations". Can I move a project from one "organization" to another? I'm starting up some projects under my personal GSuite organization, but I'll have to move them to a more professional organization and billing in the future once they are set up.

Answer (score 3):

You can't move resource across project. You have to redeploy your cloud functions in the new project.

Hopefully, cloud functions is stateless, it means you do not have data stored in it, data are stored outside, on database or file management system.